# How to write CSS based on control width?

Tags: css, html

I have a requirement, where i need to write CSS based on control current width.

Example: Let say i have `DIV`, If i place this div in side menu bar(say, `menu width="300px;"`), i want to set font size 8px and if i place this DIV in main content area(say, `menu width="700px;"`), I want to set font size `15px`.

How to acheive this scenerio using CSS ?

I know, we can write something like this with media query, but media query is based on viewport width, not parent container width.

Comment: If you don't need this to be dynamic, then you could use a css preprocessor like less or sass and "compute" the font size based on some other variable(s)

Comment: Not sure whether this is possible dynamically. I think it isn't - you'll likely need to look at JavaScript/jQuery to do this

Comment: I always thought it would be nice to have "media queries" for specific elements rather than the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the C̲ascading part of CSS:

```css
.menuBar .myDiv
{
    font-size: 8px;
}
.mainContent .myDiv
{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: perfect, i was gonna answer exactly the same.

Comment: Is it possible to write same code based on container width like we do with media query?

Answer (score 0):

```
.side-menu div{ 
 font-size:8px;}
.main-content div{ font-size:15px;}
```